# Styling First UL in blue

Tags: css

Hi I am sure it's not so hard. But i can not figure out why it fail.
I would like to use "CSS Pseudo-classes" to make first UL element become color blue. But seems it fail.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuys8.png)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `ul` isn't the :first-child. The span is the first child.

It is the [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) though.

```css
ul:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span>This span is the first child</span>
  <ul>
    <li>This list is the first-of-type</li>
  </ul>
  <span>This is another span</span>
  <ul>
    <li>This is another list</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay so what wrong you are doing is you are not specifying which child element do you refer exactly as `first-child`.
So use `ul li:first-child{/* YOUR RULE HERE */}`. This will work.